# Swagger recursive definition is rendered as "undefined" in Swagger Editor

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I am using http://editor.swagger.io `minimal.yaml` example to define a `MenuItem` which has `submenuitem` property of type `array` recursively referencing `MenuItem`. But I get `submenuitem` as `undefined`. Any pointers to what might be wrong ?

[image]

```
---
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 0.0.0
  title: Simple API
paths:
  /:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
definitions:
 MenuItem: 
       properties: 
        submenuitem: 
          items: 
            $ref: "#/definitions/MenuItem"
          title: SubMenuItem
          type: array
        display_name: 
          minLength: 2
          title: "Link display name"
          type: string
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to refer to enclosing type definition recursively in YAML / Swagger.io?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866035/how-to-refer-to-enclosing-type-definition-recursively-in-yaml-swagger-io/42845278).

Comment: This is an unresolved issue in swagger editor - https://github.com/whitlockjc/json-refs/issues/74 . 
I cannot close the question because the duplicate question do not have an accepted answer yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refer to enclosing type definition recursively in YAML / Swagger.io?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866035/how-to-refer-to-enclosing-type-definition-recursively-in-yaml-swagger-io)