# Swagger can not validate recursive data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger

I have a dto as this:

```
public class BasketItems
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("quantity")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("type")]
        public BasketItemType Type { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("children")]
        public List<BasketItems> Children { get; set; } = new List<BasketItems>();
    }
```

But Swagger doesn't understand the 'children' and expect an array of string.
How can i fix this?

Comment: This answer may help u: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866035/how-to-refer-to-enclosing-type-definition-recursively-in-openapi-swagger

Comment: @DA this fixes the Swagger example, but .net still looks for an array of string

Comment: When the link states it correct its a problem of the Swagger UI and you did not state what you use as UI. Swashbuckle maybe?

Comment: For the Swagger I don't know how to fix it but I found that .net returned error just because of  non-breaking spaces. when replaced with regular spaces it works fine.